# Storing variables used in greasemonkey script from website

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

On a certain homepage I visit I want to hide all links that I click. My idea was to use a Greasemonkey script like this:

```
var blocklist = JSON.parse(GM_getValue("blocklist"));
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var alength = as.length;   
for(var i=0; i<alength; i++) {
    var a = as[i];
    if(blocklist.indexOf(a.href) >= 0) {
        a.style.display='none';
    } else {
        a.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("HELP"); return true;');
    }
}
```

Inside the script I can call this, no problem:

```
blocklist = blocklist.concat('http://someurl');
GM_setValue("blocklist", JSON.stringify(blocklist));
```

But in the website itself (read where it says `alert("HELP");`) I cannot call this function because neither the function nor the blocklist do exist.

Is there a way to access the function from the website? (probably not?) Where else could I store the values to get them back on the next load of the website? The firefox browser is set to sanitize on shutdown, so can't use a:visited or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't try to call `GM_` functions from a webpage. (1) It's not directly possible, (2) it's a security risk, (3) it's almost never really necessary.
2. Never use `onclick` in a Greasemonkey script (or at all, really).  A simple `alert("HELP"); return true;` might work, but anything more will crash and it's bad form anyway.
3. Also, if you use `querySelectorAll` versus `getElementsByTagName`, you can fine-tune what links you process, EG: `document.querySelectorAll ("div.main a.user")` -- which would get only those links with the CSS class `user` that were inside the <div> with the class `main`.

In this case, use `addEventListener` (or use jQuery) to handle the links so your script code would become like:

```
var blocklist = JSON.parse (GM_getValue ("blocklist") );
var targlinks = document.querySelectorAll ('a');
for (var J = targlinks.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var targlink = targlinks[J];

    if (blocklist.indexOf (targlink.href) >= 0) {
        targlink.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        targlink.addEventListener ('click', virginLinkHandler, false);
    }
}

function virginLinkHandler (zEvent) {
    var newURL  = zEvent.target.href;
    blocklist   = blocklist.concat (newURL);
    GM_setValue ("blocklist", JSON.stringify (blocklist) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks weird but works great, probably because the handler is defined in the GM scope. And nice one with querySelectorAll. Sidenote: In case you want a return false you need to use zEvent.preventDefault(); instead.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about mentioning that, but it wasn't clear if it would apply in your case. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Userscripts.org looks down, so if anyone is interested, this is the result on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RiqT0C98). I just love reading the [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?pagesize=50) and was looking for a way to keep track which ones are new. Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

You should use localStorage so that you can retain your list on subsequent page loads. It's really not too different from GM_setValue.

`localStorage.setItem("blocklist", JSON.stringify(blocklist));`

`var blocklist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blocklist"));`

Comment: No. localStorage can be erased: by the site, by Firefox settings, and/or by cleaners like *CCleaner*.  `GM_setValue` is more robust and is cross-domain, to boot.

Comment: Thx, I got it running with localStorage, but closing Firefox erased all data. Will try Brock Adams' solution now. Will give you a +1 for learning something new asap.

Comment: I wasn't aware that localStorage got blown away in GM scripts, so I learned something new as well! :) good luck to you @Ikarus

Comment: It's a Firefox setting, probably "sanitizeOnShutdown" in combination with "clearOnShutdown.offlineApps".